# Adding Evernote library as a module in Android Studio gives "Class not found" when unmarshalling

Tags: android, android-studio, evernote

I'm new to Android Studio. I was developing a application in which I want to upload the documents to Evernote. I'm using Evernote SDK.

I was downloaded the Evernote Android SDK and sample app from Evernote site with the instructions given by Evernote. I was take a build of sample app and run via Android Studio then it will work correctly, but when I add the library as a module in my project and take the build it was successful.

When I'm running means the following error shows:

```
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968): Class not found when unmarshalling: com.evernote.client.android.EvernoteSession$EvernoteService
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.evernote.client.android.EvernoteSession$EvernoteService
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2133)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2097)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2013)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2314)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1118)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5285)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1586)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1167)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4496)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:4378)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:161)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3002)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/evernote/client/android/EvernoteSession$EvernoteService
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  ... 18 more
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.evernote.client.android.EvernoteSession$EvernoteService" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
05-28 18:47:04.614: E/Parcel(968):  ... 18 more
```

I was integrating the library in my project based on below points.

> Include the Android Library Project in your Intellij workspace
>
> 1. Right click your project and choose Open Module Properties
> 2. Select the Plus Icon (Add) at the top and choose Import Module
> 3. Select the library directory and click OK
> 4. Click Next, Next, Next, Next
> 5. Click Finish
> 6. Click your project and select teh Dependencies tab
> 7. Click the Plus Icon (Add) at the bottom and select 3 Module Dependency
> 8. Select library and click OK

The following are the gradle files:

Build.gradle file for library project:inside the folder library
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 5
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/evernote-api-1.25.jar')
    compile files('libs/scribe-1.3.1.jar')
}
```

build.gradle of my project : that is my project module
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xerox.xeroxmobilelink.clouddemo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':accountsManager')
    compile project(':cloudAccountsLogin')
    compile project(':cloudFolderChooser')
    compile project(':cloudDocumentUploader')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Comment: How do you integrate the library? Can you show your build.grade file?

Comment: Since you're a high-rep user, it's probably helpful for me to point out that `<br/>` tags in questions are pretty much never needed to format questions - they make posts rather more fiddly to improve/edit. Just write in ordinary line-wrapping text, and use double-carriage return to create a paragraph. Thanks! It is also worth using quote devices for quoted material (e.g. from a manual) and code formatting for blocks that benefit from monospacing (e.g. your Gradle configs here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was added activity of library in my module manifest file then it will work.
The following are the statements in manifest file inside  tag

```
<activity
        android:name="com.evernote.client.android.EvernoteOAuthActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
```

Comment: as above mentioned solution you defined not proper for evernote, i also working to integrate evernote got key and secret key can anyone explain remaining process in detail

Answer (score 0):

You are not referencing the library from maven central. Note that instruction recently was updated: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-android